# com.liferay.util.PwdGenerator

Tags: java, liferay

Quick question:

what jar do i need to add to the classpath for com.liferay.util.PwdGenerator?  I have tried a few but haven't found one that works yet.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

util-java.jar

Comment: This is the correct one, but it needs to be deployed with the portlet itself, as it's not available in the globally available classes. The required jar can easily be found by locating PwdGenerator.java in the liferay source tree. The source is organized by jars on the top level